# How can I find the seeds of the voronoi cells if I have the coordinates of the cells?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, voronoi

I want to calculate the distance between the vertex of the voronoi cell and the seed of that particular cell. However I have not been able to figure out how I can get the seed coordinate for that particular cell. I have given my code here which generates an array of cell coordinates. Could anyone tell me how I can find the corresponding seed for the particular cell?

```
import numpy as np
import freud
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import freud.box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([
    [-2, 2, 0],
    [2, 4, 0],
    [-2, 3, 0],
    [3, 5, 0]])

box = freud.box.Box(10,12, is2D= True )
voro = freud.locality.Voronoi()
cells= voro.compute((box, points)).polytopes
print(cells)
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], c= 'k')
voro.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The output of this code is the plot below and the print(cells) prints the coordinates of the cells vertices as show below.

[image]

```
[array([[-6.46875   , -1.40625   ,  0.        ],
       [-2.7       , -3.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-1.3       , -3.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.26086957, -1.52173913,  0.        ],
       [ 0.25      ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-5.1       ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-5.25      ,  2.25      ,  0.        ]]), array([[ 0.25      ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.26086957, -1.52173913,  0.        ],
       [ 3.53125   , -1.40625   ,  0.        ],
       [ 4.75      ,  2.25      ,  0.        ],
       [-1.16666667,  8.16666667,  0.        ]]), array([[-5.1       ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.25      ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-1.16666667,  8.16666667,  0.        ],
       [-1.3       ,  8.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-2.7       ,  8.5       ,  0.        ]]), array([[ 4.75      ,  2.25      ,  0.        ],
       [ 4.9       ,  2.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 7.3       ,  8.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 3.53125   , 10.59375   ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.26086957, 10.47826087,  0.        ],
       [-1.3       ,  8.5       ,  0.        ],
       [-1.16666667,  8.16666667,  0.        ]])]
```

I want to calculate the vertex to seed distance for each of the cell as indicated by the lines in the figure.

[image]

Comment: While you have shown your code, you have not provided the sample data, the expected output, and the current output required of an MRE.  For example, what is the result of ```print(cells)```

Comment: @itprorh66 Okay got it. Check the edits now.

Comment: How would you manually compute the seed of the cell?

Comment: i dont know, thats my question.

Comment: Then this is the wrong forum to be asking.  This forum is for asking specific technical issues related to programming, you are looking for a forum that addresses algorithm related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using scipy.spatial.Voronoi:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

points = np.array([
    [-2, 2],
    [2, 4],
    [1, 3],
    [-2, 3],
    [3, 5],
    [-1, 5],
    [2, 1]]
    )

vor = Voronoi(points)

print("Coordinates of point 2:")
print(vor.points[2])

print("Region for point 2:")
print(vor.point_region[2])

print("Vertices for region:")
print(vor.regions[vor.point_region[2]])

print("Coordinates of Voronoi vertices:")
print(vor.vertices[vor.regions[vor.point_region[2]]])

for vert in vor.vertices[vor.regions[vor.point_region[2]]]:
    distance = np.linalg.norm(vor.points[2]-vert)
    print("Distance between " + str(vor.points[2]) + " and " + str(vert) + " is " + str(distance))

fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

Output running the code is:

```
Coordinates of point 2:
[1. 3.]
Region for point 2:
4
Vertices for region:
[6, 4, 2, 0, 5]
Coordinates of Voronoi vertices:
[[-0.5         3.5       ]
 [ 0.5         4.5       ]
 [ 2.5         2.5       ]
 [-0.07142857  1.21428571]
 [-0.5         2.5       ]]
Distance between [1. 3.] and [-0.5  3.5] is 1.5811388300841898
Distance between [1. 3.] and [0.5 4.5] is 1.5811388300841898
Distance between [1. 3.] and [2.5 2.5] is 1.5811388300841898
Distance between [1. 3.] and [-0.07142857  1.21428571] is 2.0824828195876073
Distance between [1. 3.] and [-0.5  2.5] is 1.5811388300841898
```

The Voronoi diagram produced contains a few data structures to traverse to associate the seed point with the Voronoi vertices of the cell. Specifically:

1. `point_region` converts the point (seed) index to the associated index in the regions array
2. `regions` contains a list of indices of the Voronoi vertices for a given cell
3. `vertices` contains the coordinates of the vertices of the Voronoi cells

In the code above, the Voronoi diagram shown below is computed and the distances between the seed point and vertices are computed for the Voronoi cell in the center of the diagram.

[image: voronoi diagram]